# How to type a Tuple with many elements in Python?

Tags: python, geometry, python-typing

I am experimenting with the `typing` module and I wanted to know how to properly type something like a Nonagon (a 9 point polygon), which should be a Tuple and not a List because it should be immutable.

In 2D space, it would be something like this:

```py
Point2D = Tuple[float, float]
Nonagon = Tuple[Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D]

nine_points: Nonagon = (
    (0.0, 0.0),
    (6.0, 0.0),
    (6.0, 2.0),
    (2.0, 2.0),
    (6.0, 5.0),
    (2.0, 8.0),
    (6.0, 8.0),
    (6.0, 10.0),
    (0.0, 10.0),
)
```

Is there any syntactic sugar available to make the Nonagon declaration shorter or easier to read?

This is not valid Python, but I am looking for something similar to this:

```py
Nonagon = Tuple[*([Point2D] * 9)]  # Not valid Python
```

Or using `NamedTuple`

```py
# Not properly detected by static type analysers
Nonagon = NamedTuple('Nonagon', [(f"point_{i}", Point2D) for i in range(9)])
```

This is NOT what I want:

```py
# Valid but allows for more and less than 9 points
Nonagon = Tuple[Point2D, ...]
```

I think the most adequate way would be something like:

```py
from typing import Annotated

# Valid but needs MinMaxLen and checking logic to be defined from scratch
Nonagon = Annotated[Point2D, MinMaxLen(9, 9)]
```

Comment: Are you doing this inside of a class, or just at the module level? Also which python version is this for?

Comment: My question is more on a conceptual level so it could be either on a module level or inside a class. No Python version requirement, so I would accept an answer even if targets 3.11 or is PEP that covers this type of syntax

Comment: You should respect geometric objects, and give them a proper type; maybe a subclass of tuple?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque But what if we need to define a 100 points polygon for that matter? Having a class with 100 attributes is not something readable at all. And the question just uses geometry objects as example, this applies to constant lenght Tuples more specifically

Comment: A tuple is a product of types, so what you need is type-level integers and type-level "exponentiation" to define the product of `Point3D` with itself 9 times. Practically speaking, the fact that `Nonagon` is a type product isn't really important, and you would just define a class `Nonagon` whose constructor happens to take 9 arguments to initialize a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `types` module. All type hints come from `types.GenericAlias`.

From the doc:

> Represent a PEP 585 generic type
> E.g. for `t = list[int]`, `t.__origin__` is `list` and `t.__args__` is `(int,)`.

This means that you can make your own type hinting by passing the type arguments to the class itself.

```py
>>> Point2D = tuple[float, float]
>>> Nonagon = types.GenericAlias(tuple, (Point2D,)*9)
>>> Nonagon
tuple[tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float]]
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I am looking for, is there a way to avoid complains from mypy when doing this? I get "Variable "mymodule.Nonagon" is not valid as a type" if using TypeAlias I get "Invalid type alias: expression is not a valid type"

Comment: Why `python_typing` (are you sure you imported `types`)? It could also be the checker only allowing you to do it with literals, since this construct isn't that common. However, the syntax is correct. For example try `types.GenericAlias(tuple, (int, int)) == tuple[int, int]`, which returns `True`.

Comment: `mypy` would have to be (and doesn't appear to have been yet) written to recognize what `GenericAlias` does. Defining the type at run-time is too late for `mypy` to use it.

Comment: `python_typing` is the filename, I changed to `mymodule` to avoid confusion. Then if it isn't properly detected that should be an issue on mypy right? I follow your logic and I agree it should've been detected properly

Comment: When I tried this on pycharm, it didn't recognize that this was a type alias. So yes, technically this is the correct syntax. I'm pretty sure that no code checker is able to do this because `GenericAlias` is made during runtime. (If there is one please tell me!)

Answer (score 2):

The very first way you described it:

```py
Nonagon = Tuple[Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D, Point2D]
```

is the right way to do it, as discussed in a 2016 [python/typing](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/221) issue. Yes, it's a bit ugly, but you only have to define it once.

You could leverage `Annotated` here, but it ultimately depends on whether your typechecker can make use of the annotations that you include. Not all typecheckers would necessarily make use of those annotations, whereas spelling out how many elements should be in the tuple is something that every (functioning) typechecker should recognize.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if this would work for your purposes, but numpy might be useful here.

```
import numpy as np
ones = np.ones(9)
nonogon = ones * Point2D
```

Comment: This doesn't work - `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'types.GenericAlias'`. You can't multiply `1.0` by `tuple[float, float]`, which is a type hint.

Comment: @Greystormy I am looking for a pure Python solution, something that can be achieved with the standard library only